# MariaDB Frequently Restarting

Tags: mysql, mariadb

MariaDB is frequently (multiple times a day) restarting.

This is what I get in the mariadb.log

```
200411 18:38:51 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
200411 18:38:51 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
200411 18:38:53 mysqld_safe WSREP: Running position recovery with --log_error='/var/lib/mysql/wsrep_recovery.HWm8QZ' --pid-file='/var/lib/mysql/db-recover.pid'
200411 18:38:54 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.0.33-MariaDB-wsrep) starting as process 16103 ...
200411 18:39:01 mysqld_safe WSREP: Recovered position 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
200411 18:39:01 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.0.33-MariaDB-wsrep) starting as process 16162 ...
200411 18:39:01 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
200411 18:39:01 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
200411 18:39:01 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
200411 18:39:01 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
200411 18:39:01 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
200411 18:39:01 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
200411 18:39:01 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
200411 18:39:01 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 4.4G
200411 18:39:02 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
200411 18:39:02 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
200411 18:39:02 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
200411 18:39:02 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
200411 18:39:02 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.36-82.2 started; log sequence number 523546041827
200411 18:39:02 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
200411 18:39:02 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
200411 18:39:02 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@site-mariadb' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
200411 18:39:02 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines, skipping position init
200411 18:39:02 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library 'none'
200411 18:39:02 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.0.33-MariaDB-wsrep'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server, wsrep_25.21.rc3fc46e
```

Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: Please post the last 400 lines of your error log prior to - 200411 18:38:51 - might have some clues for us to consider.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: The entries before that in the error log are for many hours prior to this (i.e. the exact same thing happening hours earlier).

Comment: Any chance you would be able to post THREE of the sequences, with no skips from your error log?  We should then be able to see some decisions made on the startup processing.

Comment: B. I don't ever get 24 hours uptime on MariaDB anymore. For many years I did because the server only just started doing this annoying restarting thing. https://pastebin.com/DZGSRZE6 C. https://pastebin.com/Epg5Ptyr D. Process list is empty (except for the process of showing the process list!) E. https://pastebin.com/rfGXFweq

Comment: I'm not sure if it would affect the accuracy of the MySQLTuner but there's something rather odd when I was checking the sizes of tables in the information_schema.TABLES. There's a huge table (which has the same name as a tiny table) and doesn't actually seem to exist. There's no way to delete it. So if the tuner thinks that table exists and has that size (supposedly the biggest table I have) then the quoted data size would be hugely inaccurate.

Comment: Here's the log extract, showing three errors https://pastebin.com/yq62v8pA

Comment: Are there ANY rows in the error log from 200407 12:37:32 through 200411 3:37:20 you skipped in your posted data?  If so, please repost to pastebin.com to allow us to see all the error log from this start time through end time.

Comment: I didn't edit any rows out.

Comment: Observations, A) then your server ran with no interruptions in service from 200407 12:37 until 200409 18:37:35 which is 2 days and 6 hours.  B) Your server ran with no interruptions from 200409 18:37:49 until 200411 03:37:05 which is 1 day and 9 hours.  Or am I missing something about frequent restarts?

Comment: It used to run for many months without any restarts, so I'm still trying to ascertain what's causing it. It's a live production server so I don't really want the site going down every day, or every few days, or multiple times a day which sometimes happens.

Comment: I can see in the MySQLTuner report you had a horrible day yesterday. Five restarts in less than 20 minutes.  How long have you been running 10.0.33 MariaDB? Please view profile, Network profile to get contact info and from our Utility Scripts, download our free 'findfragtables.sql' script and post the results to pastebin.com for analysis.  Do you have flexibility to Skype TALK with me?  UTc - 6 hours  Skype ID is wlhauck@aol.com

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
max_connect_errors=10  # from 1 Million to frustrate hackers/crackers at 10 attempts
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
read_buffer_size=256K # from 128K to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 13,569
aria_pagecache_age_threshold=900  # from 300 to delay age out and reduce aria_pagecache_reads RPS of 1
connect_timeout=20  # from 10 to reduce aborted_connects RPhr of 60
```

There are more opportunities to improve your configuration.  Make contact, please.

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions, I have added them all to my.cnf and restarted the server. I'll give it 48 hours and report back.

Comment: Update: It's only happened once since these changes, so we have a big improvement for sure.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Is your system also quicker in query completion? And WELCOME to SO. View our profile, Network profile for contact info where we have free downloadable Utilitiy Scripts to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks for your help and suggestions. I've also just managed to fix the strange table anomaly I had, where a very small table was said to be the largest table in the database. I simply copied the table and contents, deleted the original and renamed the copy; now it's tiny as it should be! This has reduced the overall data size of the database by some margin and allowed me to slightly reduce the innodb-buffer-pool-size. This, along with reducing max-connections, has taken me out of the "danger zone" memory wise according to mysqltuner.

Comment: If your application is expected to grow in number of rows stored, it is usually most helpful to keep IBPS where it is, unless it is more than size reported in MySQLTuner * 1.4 .  ALL of MySQLTuner's suggestions might not be reasonable to apply in your configuration.  i.e. When MySQLTuner knows your server only has 8GB but they suggest using innodb_buffer_pool_size greater than total RAM, be careful.  There are others that should be carefully reviewed before jumping into your configuration.  If our suggestions helped, please consider upvote/accept.